# Перестановка элементов массива в обратном порядке

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Есть массив из 10 элементов: `1234567890`. Почему такой цикл:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 9; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = a[j];
    j--;
}
```

выдает `0987667890` вместо ожидаемого `0987654321`?
Я пытаюсь переставить элементы в обратном порядке.

Comment: Потому что вы изменяете данные. То есть при первом прохождение цикла, вы уже меняете значения a[0] вместо 1 становиться равно a[0] = 0. Как один из вариантов решения, добавьте еще один массив, и туда записывайте данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что элементы с индексами `i` и `j` нужно менять местами, а не просто присваивать элементам с индексом `i` значения оных с индексом `j`, безвозвратно теряя при этом `i`-тые значения.

Также идти надо только до середины массива, ибо если продолжать до конца массива, то при проходе от `a.length / 2` до `a.length` элементы повторно обменяются местами, в результате чего получится исходный порядок.

В итоге код выглядит так:

```
for (int i = 0, j = a.length - 1; i < a.length / 2; i++, j--)
{
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}
```

---

Также можно обойтись всего одним индексом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++)
{
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1];
    a[a.length - i - 1] = tmp;
}
```

Но это уже кому как больше нравится.

Comment: Что значит: a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1]; a[a.length - i - 1] = tmp; именно почему a[a.length - i -1] ????

Comment: @ВиталийОгородник `a.length - i -1` - это полная аналогия индекса `j` из первого варианта: начальное значение `a.length - 1` с дальнейшим уменьшением на единицу в каждой итерации